# Merge dataframes including extreme values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 data frames, df1 and df2:

```
df1
Out[66]: 
    A   B
0   1  11
1   1   2
2   1  32
3   1  42
4   1  54
5   1  66
6   2  16
7   2  23
8   3  13
9   3  24
10  3  35
11  3  46
12  3  51
13  4  12
14  4  28
15  4  39
16  4  49

df2
Out[80]: 
    B
0  32
1  42
2  13
3  24
4  35
5  39
6  49
```

I want to merge dataframes but at the same time including the first and/or last value of the set in column A. This is an example of the desired outcome:

```
df3
Out[93]: 
    A   B
0   1   2
1   1  32
2   1  42
3   1  54
4   3  13
5   3  24
6   3  35
7   3  46
8   4  28
9   4  39
10  4  49
```

I'm trying to use `merge` but that only slice the portion of data frames that coincides. Someone have an idea to deal with this? thanks!

Comment: By first / last you mean max and min ? I don't get why 2 and 54 would be in df3 otherwise

Comment: I refer to the immediately up and down row if in column A is the same number

Comment: Ok I get it, I will try some things... What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Should index 7 A=2 B=23 be part of the result since index 8  B=13 is in the list?

Comment: I started by merging both dataframes `df1.merge(df2)` then I tried to get the numbers of column A that I will need to slice by mean of `unique()` Here I can only think in to locate df2.B beside df1 and trying to chop using the position +1 and -1 However that doesn't work to keep using the same number of column A

Comment: The index 7 has not to be processed because represent the row with a different set of number in column A

Comment: Gotcha, check solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `merge` with indicator, `groupby`, and `rolling`:

```
df[df.merge(df2, on='B', how='left', indicator='Ind').eval('Found=Ind == "both"')
     .groupby('A')['Found']
     .apply(lambda x: x.rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=2).max()).astype(bool)]
```

Output:

```
    A   B
1   1   2
2   1  32
3   1  42
4   1  54
8   3  13
9   3  24
10  3  35
11  3  46
14  4  28
15  4  39
16  4  49
```

Comment: @JonathanPacheco Here's an interesting way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pd.concat([df1.groupby('A').min().reset_index(), pd.merge(df1,df2, on="B"), df1.groupby('A').max().reset_index()]).reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates().sort_values(['A','B'])
    A   B
0   1   2
4   1  32
5   1  42
1   2  16
2   3  13
7   3  24
8   3  35
3   4  12
9   4  39
10  4  49
```

Breaking down each part

```
#Get Minimum
df1.groupby('A').min().reset_index()

# Merge on B
pd.merge(df1,df2, on="B")

# Get Maximum
df1.groupby('A').max().reset_index()

# Reset the Index and drop duplicated rows since there may be similarities between the Merge and Min/Max. Sort values by 'A' then by 'B'
.reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates().sort_values(['A','B'])
```